# Office365 IMAP Access: User is Authenticated but not Connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap, office365

I'm building my own IMAP client using node-imap, and I'm testing it against accounts on office365.

Since it's under development, I tend to hammer on the IMAP server more that I would in production, but not necessarily what I would consider to be too much.

Occasionally, I start getting the IMAP response "BAD User is authenticated but not connected".  This comes after the first command after a successful login.

This is not related to password changes as other similar articles indicate, as my passwords are not changing during this time.

When this happens, the account seems to get locked up for a period of time.  I seem to be able to jiggle it free by disabling then re-enabling IMAP on the account via the office365 admin panel.

So it looks like there's a circuit breaker of some sort in the IMAP interface on office365.  Microsoft documents a limit of 20 concurrent sessions.  In my case I am only opening one session at a time, but I am then closing it and re-opening it again soon after (debugging), so if I am running afoul of a limitation, it's not documented anywhere i have read.

Microsoft support has been helpful but unable to help me root cause this.

In order to take this app to production, I need to know what causes this to happen.

Has anyone else had a similar experience with office365?

Comment: Using a cloud provider is not a great way to test code that is in development.  I would recommend installing a server you control (dovecot, courier, etc.) for initial testing/devel purposes.  Then move onto more standard compliant services (eg, gmail (minus their ridiculous folder implementation)), then onto oddballs like office365 :)

Comment: I don't disagree, but I'm kind of past that point now.  Most of my debugging is about the oddball quirks like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about disabling/enabling IMAP!  I had this problem which I believe was caused by changing the primary email address of a shared mailbox in quick succession with creating a mailing list on the old address.

Comment: 5 years later... @Jim-B Have you managed to solve that issue? I'm hitting exactly the same o365 behavior and I've got no clue what am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

you need to perform 2 operations on exchange online using powershell

You need to create the service principal

New-ServicePrincipal -AppId {clientid} -ServiceId {enterprise application objectid} -Organization {tenantid}

you need to grant your service principal access to the mailbox,
If the principal does not have the access, you get "user not connected"

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity {email} -User -ServiceId {enterprise application objectid} -AccessRights FullAccess

See "Register service principals in Exchange" at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

Comment: It works with one minor fix. It's not -User -ServiceId but -User {ServiceId}.

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity {email} -User {ServiceId (enterprise application objectid)} -AccessRights FullAccess

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the Outlook REST APIs rather than IMAP.  The REST APIs are the recommended development API for Office 365 and are much better suited for app development with features like webhook based notifications, and are constantly evolving with the new features and functionality in the service.  They also don't have the session oriented nature that IMAP has that results in the kinds of problems you are hitting.

There is a NodeJS quickstart guide to O365 here: https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/node

Comment: Ya, I'm looking at that, but the app I'm building is not just for office365.  IMAP Is technically supported, and for what I'm trying to do it's completely sufficient.  Except for this weird behavior, it's working fine.

Comment: They're definitely an improvement over every previous mail API I've used but they're still pretty green.  I ran into one deal killer bug already:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398770/outlook-rest-api-getfolders-not-returning-all-folders/35421865#35421865 
On the library side,  I need to be able to synchronize folder contents and a few other advanced features that the library doesn't expose yet so I either have to wait of develop those features myself.

Comment: The beta preview exposes a synchronization mechanism preview. You have to sync manually the folder tree and after that, use this sync mechanism. https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#SynchronizeMessagesAPI

Answer (score 0):

If you have already verified that your password is correct (by logging into your mailbox from the web) then the issue might be Exchange server keeping a list of all your active login sessions.

Try signing out from all other locations by clicking "sign out everywhere" on the account security page https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info and then retry signing in again.

Answer (score 0):

Office365 will accept connections and successfully authenticate even when the user doesn't have permissions to access the server by IMAP, and this is the exact error it gives in that situation.

To resolve it, go into the Office365 panel, open the user, and ensure that the IMAP permission is checked.