# Outlook Mail REST API: folder not found despite being in a message

Tags: directory, office365api, outlook-restapi

I try to get the list of folders of an Outlook account using the REST API.

Using the MailFolders endpoint, I only get a subset of the folders (for example I'm not getting the **Inbox** and the **Sent Items** folders).

If I list all the messages of the account and then for each message try to fetch the ParentFolderId, I get a 404 error for a bunch of them. I'm only able to get the same folders I got from the MailFolders endpoint.

Of course this works for all the other Office 365 accounts I have. And this account doesn't look different from the others.

It's not a matter of folders being renamed because I can see those folders in the Outlook UI.

Of course I correctly paginate the results when both fetching the folders or listing the messages. And again this works fine with all the other Outlook accounts.

I'm using the https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders?%24top=50 endpoint.

Any insights?

Thanks,

Jeremy

**Response**:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 

Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true‌​;IEEE754Compatible=f‌​alse;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: e98a3488-3441-474c-8cff-c905f8b9f299 
X-CalculatedFETarget: MWHPR1301CU001.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 404
X-FEProxyInfo: MWHPR1301CA0012.NAMPRD13.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-CalculatedBETarget: MWHPR16MB1661.namprd16.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 404
OData-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-DiagInfo: MWHPR16MB1661
X-BEServer: MWHPR16MB1661
X-FEServer: MWHPR1301CA0012
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: BY2PR02CA0116
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 0872CED88164470BA7F119058A1F5CBF Ref B: BAYEDGE0318 Ref C: Thu Apr 27 10:58:51 2017 PST
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 17:58:51 GMT

{
  "error":{
    "code":"ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message":"The specified object was not found in the store."
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post response headers from one of these failed requests?

Comment: Hi Jason, Here are the details of the request.

Comment: Body: `{"error":{"code":"ErrorItemNotFound","message":"The specified object was not found in the store."}}`

Comment: Headers: `< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=c7fc4cb01bfb41c884b7d6f219181e01; expires=Fri, 27-Apr-2018 17:58:51 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
< request-id: e98a3488-3441-474c-8cff-c905f8b9f299`

Comment: Headers++:`< X-CalculatedFETarget: MWHPR1301CU001.internal.outlook.com
< X-BackEndHttpStatus: 404
< X-FEProxyInfo: MWHPR1301CA0012.NAMPRD13.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
< X-CalculatedBETarget: MWHPR16MB1661.namprd16.prod.outlook.com
< X-BackEndHttpStatus: 404
< OData-Version: 4.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-DiagInfo: MWHPR16MB1661
< X-BEServer: MWHPR16MB1661
< X-FEServer: MWHPR1301CA0012
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< X-FEServer: BY2PR02CA0116
< X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 0872CED88164470BA7F119058A1F5CBF Ref B: BAYEDGE0318 Ref C: Thu Apr 27 10:58:51 2017 PST
< Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 17:58:51 GMT`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting

Comment: Thanks. We're investigating something similar so I've added your info.

Comment: @JasonJohnston Any news on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We believe this is caused by the container class property being set incorrectly on the missing folders, likely caused during an IMAP migration (migrating from an IMAP mail system into Office 365). The container class is set to `IPF.Imap` instead of the expected `IPF.Note`.

To get these folders to show up, you can change the container class using MFCMapi or EWS Editor. There are instructions on using MFCMapi to do this here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3050475/you-can-t-view-mailbox-folders-on-an-exchange-activesync-or-outlook-client-after-an-imap-migration

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll try to ask our customer to perform those actions. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Our customer used that trick to change the setting on the Inbox folder and that folder is now returned by the /me/MailFolders API call. We are checking the other folders.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by first getting a **count** of the folders and then made my second request with $top filter to get all my folders. Please see the following code:

```
$http.get("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/$count")
         .then(function(response) {
            //RETRIEVE ALL FOLDERS
            $http.get("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders?$top="+response.data).then(...)
```

Comment: Hi AidaNow, unfortunately it doesn't help. The count I get is 9 and it's already the number of folders I get when fetching them. So I'm not getting the missing ones.

Comment: I see. Have you seen this Q&A? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398770/outlook-rest-api-getfolders-not-returning-all-folders

Comment: Yes, I saw that Q&A. But one of the missing folders is the Inbox so I guess it wasn't created from an external app.